# Visual studio not executing code correctly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, runtime

Yeah so ive tried lots of stuff but the output keeps coming out all messed up. Heres a picture  showing whats going on. As you see the letter variable gets all weird.

[image: http://img249.imageshack.us/img249/8775/weirdvisstud.png]

Comment: can't read the printout in your post, please add the output as text

Comment: Please replace the picture with the correct text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `"letter: " + letter"` doesn't do what you think it does, it adds the integral value of letter to the `const char*` string literal `"letter"`. Easiest fix is `string("letter: ") + letter`.

Comment: Ah... Thanks! can also change "letter: " + letter to "letter: " << letter :) Thanks for your help!